# Hello I am trying to solve and exercise on action of grupoids on sets

Tags: general-topology, category-theory

(a) Let G be a group. Recall that BG is a groupoid with one object ∗ whose automorphism
group is G (with g ◦h = gh). Let SetG be the category of left G-sets: objects are sets with a left action of G, and morphisms are G-equivariant maps. Show that
there is an equivalence of categories
Fun(BG, Set) ≃ SetG.
(b) Let E : C → C' be an equivalence of categories. Show that the induced functor Fun(C',D) → Fun(C, D)
F   → F ◦ E
is an equivalence for any category D.
I am trying to solve this exercise and I wanted to use the characterization of equivalence of categories but I have some problems on how to formalize it, especially the a)
Any help is welcome

Comment: please only ask one question at a time. Especially since your two questions are not directly related. It sounds like you mostly want help on (a), so maybe edit your question to focus on (a). Try to include more details about what you've tried so far

Answer (score 1):

Lets first unpack what functor $BG \to Set$ is. This consists of an assignment of objects in $BG$ to sets. Since there is just one object in $BG$, we are just choosing a single set. Suppose we choose the set $X$ as the image of the unique $X$. Then, we have a function $BG(\star , \star) \to Set(X , X)$. Since every functor preserves isomorphisms, this amounts to a choices of automorphisms of $X$ for each $g \in G$.

But this choice of automorphism, i.e., the function $BG(\star , \star) \to Set(X,X)$ has some requirements imposed by functoriality. It must send $1_\star$ to $1_X$ and it must preserve composition of function. In other words, it preserves the group operation. If you unpack these requirements a bit further, you'll find that this is exactly the conditions required of a group action.

In some sense, this argument goes the other way. Take a group homomorpism $G \to Aut(X)$. You'll find that the group homomorphism conditions are exactly the conditions required to make this map the action on morphisms of a functor $BG \to Set$ that sends $\star$ to $X$.

Heres one way to think about this. Recall that a functor $BG \to HG$ is equivalent to a group homomorphism between $G$ and $H$. What you are proving in this question is in a sense a generalization of this fact (it might already be obvious how). As even more of a generalization, we can prove that a functor $F : C \to D$ induces a group homomorphism $Aut(c) \to Aut (F(c))$ for each $c$ in $C$. When we apply this to your question, we have $Aut(\star) = G$. So a functor $F : BG \to Set$ induces a group homomorphism $G \to Aut(X)$, since we stipulated $F(\star) = X$. But, since there is only one object $\star$ in $BG$, such a functor is just equivalent to a choice of $F(\star)$ and such a homomorphism.